# What happens to a transaction if the server crashes

Tags: t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2012

I know I could just test this but don't want to take down my server.

If a transaction is not yet committed and the SQL server crashes will the transaction be rolled back when the server recovers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** - all transactions that haven't been committed will be rolled back when the server starts up again (thanks to the transaction log that SQL Server keeps)

For more in depth info, see Paul Randal's blog post [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (1/30) in-flight transactions continue after a failover](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-130-in-flight-transactions-continue-after-a-failover/)